# Where can I get the defaul proguard files for R8

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

I'm working on an app in Android Studio 3.6 and I've just realised that I seem to be missing the `proguard-android.txt` or `proguard-android-optimize.txt` and `proguard-rules.pro` files.

They are defined in my build.gradle (app) file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

but I do not have these files shwoing anywhere in my project tree or in the project folders.

I am using gradle 3.6.3 according to my `build.gradle (ProjectName)` file so I know that `R8` will actually be used rather than ProGuard, but I understand (from https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code) that R8 still uses the same files to define what should be optimized and what should be kept etc.

I want to make sure that my app is optimized and obfuscated but I also need to protect some code with `-keep` clauses which I believe need to go into the `proguard-rules.pro` file.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Why do I not have these files?
2. How do I get hold of the latest official defaul files as a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

The content of these files are built from the text files in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/resources/com/android/build/gradle.

Based on the name of the argument to `getDefaultProguardFile` one or more of these resources are selected as configuration files in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/ProguardFiles.java.